# How to resolve "Transactions API must be enabled before using"

Tags: node.js, transactions, actions-on-google

I am trying to develop my first AoG action that works with `transactions` and `order`. In doing so, in the `node.js` fulfillment code I used the exact code as shown in *Build reservations* in https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-reservations#troubleshooting.

In my fulfillment I use the `order` object as shown on the `Node.js` tab under *2. Build the order* (https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-reservations#fulfillment_2) 

and the code for the `TransactionDecision` instance under *3. Propose the order* (https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-reservations#fulfillment_3)

I then use the following code for generating the response:

```
          const order = ... // from 'Build the order'

          let td = new TransactionDecision({
            orderOptions: {
              requestDeliveryAddress: 'false',
            },
            presentationOptions: {
              actionDisplayName: 'RESERVE',
            },
            order: order 
          });

          conv.ask(td);
```

When I try to test this in the Actions on Google Actions Console, I get the following error message in the log:

```
MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0]: Transactions API must be enabled before using
{
 insertId: "ofgpz4fqpyuj4"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/huismeester-21dea/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-10-07T11:57:38.323616528Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0]: Transactions API must be enabled before using"  
 timestamp: "2019-10-07T11:57:38.315740302Z"  
 trace: "projects/84695521529/traces/ABwppHHPuMPb-ybvyUKvtbrWR5lyDCb00dW5vMunLreeqLb0XbWPF_UINvjbOMF4W_akp2ca9noZGCceZuphXZc"  
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or which step I am forgetting? I am using actionssdk:

```
const app = actionssdk({ ordersv3: true });
```

Also, in the *Actions Console* under *Deploy | Additional Information*, I ticked the two check marks under *Transactions*.

Kind regards,